# Is it possible to deallocate C __thread thread-local memory once the thread exited?

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-local, thread-local-storage

I have a thread-safe function and I want to allocate a dynamic thread-local memory buffer to use it independently and be able to deallocate it once the thread exited. Here's the demo:

```
void func_needs_storage(void) {
    static __thread void* tlb = NULL;

    if (!tlb)
        tlb = malloc(sizeof(int));

    printf("Thread id: %08lx, local tlb address is: %08lx\n",
            (uintptr_t)pthread_self(), (uintptr_t)tlb);
}

void* thread_func(void *) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        func_needs_storage();

    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t threads[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(threads) / sizeof(*threads); ++i)
        if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread_func, NULL))
            return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(threads) / sizeof(*threads); ++i)
        if (pthread_join(threads[i], NULL))
            return 2;

    return 0;
}
```

> Note that I **can't** allocate/free memory in the `thread_func`
>   The output is:

```
Thread id: 7efda7cdd700, local tlb address is: 7efda0000b20 <-- 1st thread
Thread id: 7efda7cdd700, local tlb address is: 7efda0000b20
Thread id: 7efda84de700, local tlb address is: 7efda0000f50 <-- 2nd thread
Thread id: 7efda84de700, local tlb address is: 7efda0000f50
Thread id: 7efda8cdf700, local tlb address is: 7efda0000f70 <-- 3rd thread
Thread id: 7efda8cdf700, local tlb address is: 7efda0000f70
```

It works as a charm, but unfortunately, this code creates an inevitable memory leak :(

Here `func_needs_storage()` is a function that needs a temporary buffer to process some data and it may be called many times. The memory it uses **should be dynamic and may be quite large** (up to megabytes) and could be hardly placed on stack. I don't wanted to allocate the buffer each time the function is called, so I stored the pointer to it in a thread-local static variable, unique for each thread.

The question is: is it possible to **deallocate this thread-local memory buffer** in C, when the thread exited and it is **guaranteed **that this memory won't be used anymore? Maybe I should use some `pthread` API or declare my variable somehow other than `__thread`? The compiler is the latest gcc/clang the OS is archlinux/freebsd.

As a reference example in C++ I could wrap my buffer in a `ThreadLocalStorage` class and make the destructor that deallocates its internal memory. Then, if a declare a `static thread_local ThreadLocalStorage`, it's destructor will be called once this thread exited.

Comment: Is changing the signature of `func_needs_storage` possible (adding a parameter)?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm maybe, depending on what exactly you propose

Comment: You can't deallocate the thread-local storage, but since it only takes 4 or 8 bytes per thread you never worry about that.  The thread needs to call free() to avoid a leak.

Comment: *The memory it uses should be dynamic and may be quite large (up to megabytes) and could be hardly placed on stack.*  Why **can't** the memory be place on the stack?  You have [complete control over the size of the stack used for a POSIX thread](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_attr_setstacksize.html).

Comment: @AndrewHenle that’s a good point, Andrew, I’ll check it tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm back. I have used the [pthread_key_create()](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pthread_key_create&sektion=3&manpath=freebsd-release-ports), [pthread_setspecific()](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pthread_setspecific&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports) and [pthread_getspecific()](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=pthread_getspecific&sektion=3&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD%2012.1-RELEASE%20and%20Ports) functions to solve my task and I want to share my solution with you, hope that it'll help someone.

```
static pthread_key_t key;
static pthread_once_t key_once = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;

void key_destructor(void* tlb) {
    printf("Thread id: %08lx, deallocate local tlb address: %08lx\n",
        (uintptr_t)pthread_self(), (uintptr_t)tlb);

    free(tlb);
}

void make_key_once(void) {
    pthread_key_create(&key, key_destructor /* or just "free" */);
}

void func_needs_storage(void) {
    pthread_once(&key_once, make_key_once);

    void* tlb = NULL;
    if ((tlb = pthread_getspecific(key)) == NULL) 
    {
        tlb = malloc(sizeof(int));
        pthread_setspecific(key, tlb);
    }

    printf("Thread id: %08lx, local tlb address is: %08lx\n",
        (uintptr_t)pthread_self(), (uintptr_t)tlb);
}

void* thread_func(void *) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        func_needs_storage();

    return NULL;
}

int main() {
    pthread_t threads[3];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(threads) / sizeof(*threads); ++i)
        if (pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, thread_func, NULL))
            return 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(threads) / sizeof(*threads); ++i)
        if (pthread_join(threads[i], NULL))
            return 2;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
Thread id: 881b309c0, local tlb address is: 200bb81e0
Thread id: 881b309c0, local tlb address is: 200bb81e0
Thread id: 881b309c0, local tlb address is: 200bb81e0
Thread id: 881b309c0, deallocate local tlb address: 200bb81e0
Thread id: 881b30e40, local tlb address is: 200bb81e0
Thread id: 881b30e40, local tlb address is: 200bb81e0
Thread id: 881b30e40, local tlb address is: 200bb81e0
Thread id: 881b30e40, deallocate local tlb address: 200bb81e0
Thread id: 881b312c0, local tlb address is: 200bb81e0
Thread id: 881b312c0, local tlb address is: 200bb81e0
Thread id: 881b312c0, local tlb address is: 200bb81e0
Thread id: 881b312c0, deallocate local tlb address: 200bb81e0
```

The memory is reused. Let's add some delay to the func_needs_storage() to prove that it works:

```
Thread id: 8815e49c0[0], local tlb address is: 20062c1e0{0}
Thread id: 8815e52c0[1], local tlb address is: 20062c300{1}
Thread id: 8815e4e40[2], local tlb address is: 20062c2e0{2}
Thread id: 8815e4e40[2], local tlb address is: 20062c2e0{2}
Thread id: 8815e49c0[0], local tlb address is: 20062c1e0{0}
Thread id: 8815e52c0[1], local tlb address is: 20062c300{1}
Thread id: 8815e49c0[0], local tlb address is: 20062c1e0{0}
Thread id: 8815e49c0[0], deallocate local tlb address: 20062c1e0{0}
Thread id: 8815e4e40[2], local tlb address is: 20062c2e0{2}
Thread id: 8815e4e40[2], deallocate local tlb address: 20062c2e0{2}
Thread id: 8815e52c0[1], local tlb address is: 20062c300{1}
Thread id: 8815e52c0[1], deallocate local tlb address: 20062c300{1}
```

If you're not dead-limited to C (as I was) and allowed to use C++ in your code, use the `thread_local` [storage class specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) as the object's destructor will be called for each `thread_local` object upon thread termination making possible to release the memory of the FD.

Pro tip: Have a closer look at your OS's thread management system (how does it store the TLS areas and handle thread termination). We use the FreeBSD 9 fork with very peculiar thread management system.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't use `pthread_cancel()` or otherwise kill a running thread, move the `tlb` declaration to file scope and `free()` it right before `thread_func()` returns:

```
static __thread void* tlb = NULL;

void* thread_func(void *) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        func_needs_storage();

    free( tlb );
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I can neither allocate nor free memory in the thread_func, plese note my remark. The demo is a simplified version of the exact state of the art.

Comment: @Netherwire Why not?

Comment: @Netherwire Then you have a design problem, not a code problem.

Comment: @dbush because thread_func is not my code. The function that allocates memory is a part of my bridge library. thread_func just indicates an entry point.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using a thread local variable in `func_needs_storage`, allocate the memory in `thread_func`, pass it to `func_needs_storage`, then free it when `thread_func` completes.

```
void func_needs_storage(void *tlb) {

    printf("Thread id: %08lx, local tlb address is: %08lx\n",
            (uintptr_t)pthread_self(), (uintptr_t)tlb);
}

void* thread_func(void *) {
    void *tlb = malloc(sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        func_needs_storage(tlb);

    free(tlb);
    return NULL;
}
```